# Make string and color bindable

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

I have some code like the following where I want to update a string and a color through SwiftUI's binding but I get these errors:

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding' conform to 'StringProtocol'

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Color?'

```
import SwiftUI

struct PasswordStrengthIndicator: View {
    private let segment = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: CGFloat(4))

    @State private var segmentColor = Color.gray
    @State private var hintText = ""

    var body: some View {
       VStack {
           segment
               .foregroundColor($segmentColor)
           Text($hintText)
       }
       .onAppear(perform: onAppear)
    }

    func onAppear() {
       segmentColor = Color.red
       hintText = "Enter password!"
    }
}
```

If I remove the `$` binding indicator I get no errors but text and color does not get updated. How do I fix these issues in SwiftUI 2 without overcomplicating the code?

UPDATE:

Above code works but it does not work if the text/color change is done in a method called from a parent view, e.g.:

```
    func onAppear() {
    }

    // Called from parent view.
    func updateStrengthIndication() {
       segmentColor = Color.red
       hintText = "Enter password!"
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "text and color does not get updated"? When I run your code without $ the segment is red and it says "EnterPassword!".

Comment: The code you posted works just fine, the foreground is red and the text is "Enter password!". If you put also a button to change the color and the text, it also works fine.

Comment: That's weird! It doesn't work for me. my actual code is somewhat more complex but not by much. The only notable difference is that values for text and color are assigned from constants wrapped in structs.

Comment: If I use ```struct Test {
    static let color = Color.gray
    static let text = ""
}``` as initial values it still works for me. Maybe you could extend your question to include your actual use case?

Comment: The above works if I use it as that and change the text and color in `onAppear` but it does not change if I call it in a method, e.g. `func updateStrengthIndication()` from a parent view that wraps `PasswordStrengthIndicator` as a child view. That seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: In this scenario you should probably use @Binding in `PasswordStrengthIndicator` and declare the `@State` variables in your parent view.

Comment: @finebel but that seems inelegant since the segments and text have no business  in the parent view and should be private to the PasswordStrengthIndicator view.

Comment: It is obvious confusing SwiftUI binding concept, please re-read SwiftUI documentation (and/or corresponding WWDC sessions) again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok an alternative would be to create an extra View Model for your `PasswordStrengthIndicator` View which you could then wrap in the View Model of your parent view.

```
// MARK: - Parent View
class ParentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var childViewModel = PasswordStrengthIndicatorViewModel()
 
    func updateBtnDidTab() {
        childViewModel.updateIndicator()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var parentVM = ParentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PasswordStrengthIndicator(
                viewModel: parentVM.childViewModel
            )
            
            Button("Change", action: parentVM.updateBtnDidTab)
        }
        
    }
}

// MARK: - Child View
class PasswordStrengthIndicatorViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var segmentColor = Color.gray
    @Published private(set) var hintText = ""
    
    func updateIndicator() {
        segmentColor = Color.green
        hintText = "asdf"
    }
}

struct PasswordStrengthIndicator: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PasswordStrengthIndicatorViewModel
    
    private let segment = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: CGFloat(4))

    var body: some View {
       VStack {
           segment
               .foregroundColor(viewModel.segmentColor)
           Text(viewModel.hintText)
       }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Displaying a preview for `PasswordStrengthIndicatorViewModel`:

```
struct PasswordStrengthIndicator_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PasswordStrengthIndicator(
            viewModel: PasswordStrengthIndicatorViewModel()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work but there are several compromises: the parent view now needs to manage the state of the child view it normally shouldn't know about, the `PasswordStrengthIndicatorViewModel ` now has to contain all the logic for evaluating the password strength (it was in `PasswordStrengthIndicator` before), and all the value constant structs have to be made non-private so `PasswordStrengthIndicatorViewModel` can access them.

One question: How do you write `PasswordStrengthIndicator_Previews` with the new argument requirement in the constructor?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example for the preview.

Comment: You're right, and the `PasswordStrengthIndicatorViewModel ` class can be wrapped inside PasswordStrengthIndicator struct so the included constant structs can remain private.

Comment: Cool :-). In addition I think it's better to have the logic for evaluating the strength of a password inside a view model, because this way you can decouple the logic from your actual view implementation.